# Minikube - files disappear after restart

Tags: minikube

I'm using `minikube` version 0.28.0 and files don't persist after a minikube restart.

I ran into the problem after noticing my database data disappears after a restart (even though the pods, `pv`'s, and `pvc`'s say they've been up for days). I used `minikube ssh` to create some files and noticed those disappear, too.

FWIW - I ran `minikube addons list` to confirm that `default-storageclass` is enabled

Should I be using `minikube --mount` to mount my data to my dev machine's disk? How can I persist my pods' data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is explained on [Persistent Volumes](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/reference/persistent_volumes/).

> minikube supports [PersistentVolumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) of type `hostPath` out of the box. These PersistentVolumes are mapped to a directory inside the running Minikube instance (usually a VM, unless you use `--vm-driver=none`).
>
> ...
>
> minikube is configured to persist files stored under the following directories, which are made in the Minikube VM (or on your localhost if running on bare metal). You may lose data from other directories on reboots.
>
> - `/data`
> - `/var/lib/minikube`
> - `/var/lib/docker`
> - `/tmp/hostpath_pv`
> - `/tmp/hostpath-provisioner`

As for mounting please read the Minikube docs, [Filesystem mounts](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/tasks/mount/).

> To mount a directory from the host into the guest using the  `mount`  subcommand:
>
> ```
> minikube mount <source directory>:<target directory>
> ```
>
> For example, this would mount your home directory to appear as /host within the minikube VM:
>
> ```
> minikube mount $HOME:/host
> ```